# Xbox 360 PDP Controller not working with Ouya

Tags: controllers, ouya

I recently bought an Ouya, and a [second xbox 360 PDP Rock Candy controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008U2XJP8) (my girlfriend liked it and it was cheap hahah), but I can't get it to work.

I plug it in, and halfway through it lights up, but then it simply turns off and I can't get it to do anything at all.

[This thread on ouyaforums](http://ouyaforum.com/showthread.php?4518-Rock-Candy-360-Controller-Help) was dealing with the same problem, and solved it with a firmware update. I just barely bought my Ouya and it updated when I first used it, and I even re-checked it to see if there was something like that going on, but no updates to be found.

Should I just return it? I'd rather get it working!

Comment: Damn, that's an ugly controller.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes there are little bugs in fake controllers which powerful computers like Xbox cannot handle so they give a message like error for example. My answer is to buy a new controller or try to fix the bug or use a adapter.